# How to import component to ReactHtmlParser

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, components

I want to understand how to use the react component for ReactHtmlParser, it returns [object Object]

```
const button = <Button variant="contained">Default</Button>
const color = `red`
const HTML = `<p style="color: ${color}"> Hello World, my name is Jacob! ${button} </p>`


export class HtmlParse extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <>
                {ReactHtmlParser(HTML)}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I don't want to create a `<button> String </button>`, `const HTML = <button> String </button>` tag inside an HTML variable every time, i want to create ready-made components and import

Answer (score 0):

That does look right. Does it render if you do?

```
<div><HtmlParse/> </div>
```

Comment: Yes, in App.js I call this way

Answer (score 0):

You are adding JSX to the parsed HTMl. Try removing the button from the HTML and adding it to JSX.
const button = "Default"
const color = `red`
const HTML = `<p style="color: ${color}"> Hello World, my name is Jacob! ${button}</p>`

```
export class HtmlParse extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <>
                {ReactHtmlParser(HTML)}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention to this picture https://ibb.co/xqWZ5wx for me it also works with the button just returns `[object Object]` and I want to return the button instead

Comment: Updated the answer.  The <Button> gets transformed into function call that returns and object. Not a string. Don't parse the <Button> react component, but add it before or after the parsed html.

Comment: I did update it to code above, that should work.

Comment: Yes, I saw, but the problem I have is that I want to apply the button anywhere for example after the word "Hello World"

Comment: Then you need to use html instead of JSX. ReactHTMLParser parses html, not jsx. Updated again. 
You will face difficulties when adding call handlers there though, now you need to listen to button clicks without react. It would be easier to have several templates, and use jsx for button